# Cannot install "oracle" npm on ubuntu

Tags: oracle, node.js

I got the following error message when I try to install oracle npm module on my ubuntu box:

```
npm install oracle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oracle
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oracle

> oracle@0.1.2 install /home/luc/node_modules/oracle
> node-waf configure build

Setting srcdir to                        : /home/luc/node_modules/oracle 
Setting blddir to                        : /home/luc/node_modules/oracle/build 
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : ok /home/luc/.nave/installed/0.6.12/lib/node 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /home/luc/.nave/installed/0.6.12 
Checking for header occi.h               : Missing include files for OCI 
/home/luc/node_modules/oracle/wscript:28: error: the configuration failed (see '/home/luc/node_modules/oracle/build/config.log')
npm ERR! error installing oracle@0.1.2

npm ERR! oracle@0.1.2 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the oracle@0.1.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.38-8-server
npm ERR! command "node" "/home/luc/.nave/installed/0.6.12/bin/npm" "install" "oracle"
npm ERR! cwd /home/luc
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message oracle@0.1.2 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/luc/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

My env variables seem to be correctly set:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/luc/instantclient_11_2/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
```

and the symlink as well:

```
libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1
libocci.so -> libocci.so.11.1
```

Is there something missing in my config ?

Comment: i would guess that you are missing include files for OCI.

Comment: @andrew-cooke, my bad.... export OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=$ORACLE_HOME/sdk/include/ and export OCI_LIB_DIR=$ORACLE_HOME fixed the thing. Could you please make your comment an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heh :o)  ok, so just reading the error message above, it looks like the OCI include files are missing... (i have no idea what those are, even!)